# AngularJS ng-repeat Post Value not getting in proper pattern using id as key

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS I want to get post value in proper format. When I use
field name as key in checkbox it gives proper value but when I use id as key it does't.

Given below code with name as key

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mainMenu = {};
  $scope.submenu = {};
  $scope.pagemenu ={};
  $scope.menu   = {};
  
  $scope.menus  = [
    {"menuID":"11","sub_menu":"N","name":"dashboard","sub_menus":""},
    {"menuID":"1","sub_menu":"Y","name":"settings","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"settings1","page":"Y","pages":[{"pageID":"1","name":"page1"},{"pageID":"2","name":"page2"}]},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"settings2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
    {"menuID":"2","sub_menu":"Y","name":"help","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"3","name":"help1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"4","name":"help2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
    {"menuID":"3","sub_menu":"Y","name":"contact","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"5","name":"contact1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"6","name":"contact2","page":"N","pages":""}]}
  ];
  
  $scope.assignValue = function(menuId,submenuId,pageId){
    /* if(!$scope.mainMenu[menuId]&&!$scope.submenu[menuId]&&!$scope.pagemenu[menuId]){
      delete($scope.mainMenu[menuId]);
      delete($scope.submenu[menuId]);
      delete($scope.pagemenu[menuId]);
    } */
    
    $scope.menu=Object.assign({},$scope.mainMenu, $scope.submenu,$scope.pagemenu);
    console.log($scope.menu);
  }
  
  $scope.submit = function(){
    // alert(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
    console.log($scope.menu);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>rules</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mainCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <form ng-submit="submit()">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="x in menus">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID)" ng-model="mainMenu[x.name]" ng-true-value="'{{x.menuID}}'">{{x.name}}
            <ul ng-if="[x.sub_menu] == 'Y'">
              <li ng-repeat="subMenu in x.sub_menus">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="submenu[x.name][subMenu.name]" ng-true-value="'{{subMenu.sub_menuID}}'" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,null)">{{subMenu.name}}
                <ul ng-if="[subMenu.page] == 'Y'">
                  <li ng-repeat="page in subMenu.pages">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pagemenu[x.name][subMenu.name][page.name]"  ng-true-value="'{{page.pageID}}'" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,page.pageID)">{{page.name}}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code with id as key

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mainMenu = {};
  $scope.submenu = {};
  $scope.pagemenu ={};
  $scope.menu   = {};
  $scope.menus  = [
    {"menuID":"11","sub_menu":"N","name":"dashboard","sub_menus":""},
    {"menuID":"1","sub_menu":"Y","name":"settings","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"settings1","page":"Y","pages":[{"pageID":"1","name":"page1"},{"pageID":"2","name":"page2"}]},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"settings2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
    {"menuID":"2","sub_menu":"Y","name":"help","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"3","name":"help1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"4","name":"help2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
    {"menuID":"3","sub_menu":"Y","name":"contact","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"5","name":"contact1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"6","name":"contact2","page":"N","pages":""}]}
  ];
  
  $scope.assignValue = function(menuId,submenuId,pageId){
    /* if(!$scope.mainMenu[menuId]&&!$scope.submenu[menuId]&&!$scope.pagemenu[menuId]){
      delete($scope.mainMenu[menuId]);
      delete($scope.submenu[menuId]);
      delete($scope.pagemenu[menuId]);
    }*/
    
    $scope.menu=Object.assign({},$scope.mainMenu, $scope.submenu,$scope.pagemenu);
    console.log($scope.menu);
  }
  
  $scope.submit = function(){
    // alert(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
    console.log($scope.menu);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>rules</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mainCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <form ng-submit="submit()">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="x in menus">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID)" ng-model="mainMenu[x.menuID]" ng-true-value="'{{x.menuID}}'">{{x.name}}
            <ul ng-if="[x.sub_menu] == 'Y'">
              <li ng-repeat="subMenu in x.sub_menus">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="submenu[x.menuID][subMenu.sub_menuID]" ng-true-value="'{{subMenu.sub_menuID}}'" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,null)">{{subMenu.name}}
                <ul ng-if="[subMenu.page] == 'Y'">
                  <li ng-repeat="page in subMenu.pages">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pagemenu[x.menuID][subMenu.sub_menuID][page.pageID]"  ng-true-value="'{{page.pageID}}'" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,page.pageID)">{{page.name}}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: {"11":"11","1":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"2":{"3":"3","4":"4"}‌​,"3":{"5":"5","6":"6‌​"}}

Comment: show what you want in your question.

Comment: also use ng-repeat="(key,value) in menus" and same with others.. That will make your work easy.

Comment: can u please tell me how to use ng-repeat="(key,value) in menus"

Comment: I surely will.. but just tell me what output do you want

Comment: i want output like :- 
{"11":"11","1":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"2":{"3":"3","4":"4"}‌​‌​,"3":{"5":"5","6":‌​"6‌​"}} 

but i get :- 
{"1":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2"}},"2":{"3":"3","4":"4"},"3":{"5":"5","6":"6"},"11":"11"}


after all checkbox checked

Comment: when you aren't using any Ids in your assignValue() function, why do you need to pass them from view ???

Comment: actually i use copied code. i don't know what assignValue() function works.

Comment: alright.. so is it just the order of the keys you are worried about ?

Comment: yes  @Tirthraj Barot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed your code and compared the results. The only difference that I figured out was of the order you wants the key to be in.

In json, there is no meaning of ordering keys. Moreover your keys are numbers so they are arranged in an ascending order.

It's the way v8 handles associative arrays. A known issue Issue 164 but it follows the spec so is marked 'working as intended'. There isn't a required order for looping through associative arrays.

A simple workaround is to precede number values with letters e.g: 'size_7':['9149','9139'] etc.

The standard will change in the next ECMAScript spec forcing [chrome] developers to change this.

So nothing to worry about the order. You can access it with the keys as that is how json is to be used.

If you need order then you need some dirty hacky ways to do it which will either force you to rename your keys to something else or to create sub-objects of json.

For your case, the hacky way is to add `_` before all your menuIds except `11`

This will make you menus array look like below

```
  $scope.menus  = [
    {"menuID":"11","sub_menu":"N","name":"dashboard","sub_menus":""},
    {"menuID":"_1","sub_menu":"Y","name":"settings","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"settings1","page":"Y","pages":[{"pageID":"1","name":"page1"},{"pageID":"2","name":"page2"}]},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"settings2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
    {"menuID":"_2","sub_menu":"Y","name":"help","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"3","name":"help1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"4","name":"help2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
    {"menuID":"_3","sub_menu":"Y","name":"contact","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"5","name":"contact1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"6","name":"contact2","page":"N","pages":""}]}
  ];
```

and this will provide you with the desired output of `11` to be the first element and `_1`,`_2` and `_3` following it.

Here is the code snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mainMenu = {};
  $scope.submenu = {};
  $scope.pagemenu = {};
  $scope.menu = {};
  $scope.menus = [{
      "menuID": "11",
      "sub_menu": "N",
      "name": "dashboard",
      "sub_menus": ""
    },
    {
      "menuID": "_1",
      "sub_menu": "Y",
      "name": "settings",
      "sub_menus": [{
        "sub_menuID": "1",
        "name": "settings1",
        "page": "Y",
        "pages": [{
          "pageID": "1",
          "name": "page1"
        }, {
          "pageID": "2",
          "name": "page2"
        }]
      }, {
        "sub_menuID": "2",
        "name": "settings2",
        "page": "N",
        "pages": ""
      }]
    },
    {
      "menuID": "_2",
      "sub_menu": "Y",
      "name": "help",
      "sub_menus": [{
        "sub_menuID": "3",
        "name": "help1",
        "page": "N",
        "pages": ""
      }, {
        "sub_menuID": "4",
        "name": "help2",
        "page": "N",
        "pages": ""
      }]
    },
    {
      "menuID": "_3",
      "sub_menu": "Y",
      "name": "contact",
      "sub_menus": [{
        "sub_menuID": "5",
        "name": "contact1",
        "page": "N",
        "pages": ""
      }, {
        "sub_menuID": "6",
        "name": "contact2",
        "page": "N",
        "pages": ""
      }]
    }
  ];

  $scope.assignValue = function(menuId, submenuId, pageId) {
    $scope.menu = Object.assign({}, $scope.mainMenu, $scope.submenu, $scope.pagemenu);
    console.log($scope.menu);
  }

  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
    console.log($scope.menu);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in menus">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-change="assignValue(x.menuID)" ng-model="mainMenu[x.menuID]" ng-true-value="'{{x.menuID}}'">{{x.name}}
          <ul ng-if="[x.sub_menu] == 'Y'">
            <li ng-repeat="subMenu in x.sub_menus">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="submenu[x.menuID][subMenu.sub_menuID]" ng-true-value="'{{subMenu.sub_menuID}}'" ng-change="assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,null)">{{subMenu.name}}
              <ul ng-if="[subMenu.page] == 'Y'">
                <li ng-repeat="page in subMenu.pages">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pagemenu[x.menuID][subMenu.sub_menuID][page.pageID]" ng-true-value="'{{page.pageID}}'" ng-change="assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,page.pageID)">{{page.name}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```